# Преобразовать список после zip()

Tags: python

```py
# изначально был список
list1 = [[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[2,2],[1,2,3,4]]
result = []
    for element in list1:
        if len(element )!=2:
            result.append([[x, y] for x,y in zip(element , element[1:])])
        else:
            result.append(element )
print(result)
#
```

***Вывод***

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 1]], 
[[0, 0], [0, 1]], 
[[0, 0], [0, 1]], 
[2, 2], 
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]]
```

***Нужный вывод***

```
[[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[2,2],[1,2,3,4]]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, получаю на входе такой вот список. Как привести его формат к изначальному? до того, как я применил `zip()`.
На всякий случай уточню, что `list1` подается каждый раз разный. Он берется из запроса через psycopg. Т.е просто убрать какие-то индексы не получится. В идеале какая-то проверка. Я пробовал через `len()`, но получается, что количество элементах в писке списков `[[0, 0], [0, 1]],  [2, 2]` одинаковое и равно `2`

Comment: вопрос: что такое `cort`? Добавьте еще описание, что вы делаете

Comment: @Dmitry, просто элемент в изначальном списке

Comment: дайте весь код, относящийся к вопросу

Comment: @Dmitry, добавил

Comment: обратил внимание. Еще добавьте нужный вывод. И обратите внимание на ваш список, при таком определении у вас должно вылетать `SynataxError`, вот здесь лишняя запятая `...,[,1,2,3,4]]`

Comment: @Dmitry, постарался все добавить

Comment: Проверьте ввод, у меня выводит это: 
[[[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [0, 1]], [2, 2], [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]], у вас в последнем списке возникает [0, 0]

Comment: @DavidusCorvus, исправил вывод

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) определяет тип первого элемента списка:

```
def connect_one(lst):
    first = lst[0]
    if isinstance(first, list):
        return [first[0]] + [sublist[-1] for sublist in lst]
    return lst


def connect(lst):
    return list(map(connect_one, lst))


print(connect([
    [[0, 0], [0, 1]], 
    [[0, 0], [0, 1]], 
    [[0, 0], [0, 1]], 
    [2, 2], 
    [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
]))
```

> ```
> $ python connect.py
> [[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
> ```

Comment: Нужный вывод `[[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[2,2],[1,2,3,4]]`, у вас элемент из каждого элемента списка потерян

Comment: Поправил вывод.

Comment: Подскажите, почему если элемент `[2,2]` находится в конце, то выводится `None`?

Comment: @Nommad, какие данные на входе?

Comment: на вход передается список, который я получаю из запросом из бд. Я добавил проверку на равность индексов. Если равны,  то элемент добавляется в новый список, `else:` он проваливается в Вашу функцию. Вроде работает